# Problema de ir ao servidor ao carregar componente tinyMCE

Tags: html, asp.net, tinymce

Quando insiro informações no componente tinyMCE e clico em qualquer botão que submete o formulário tem me gerado o erro.

> Erro em tempo de execução do JavaScript:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Ocorreu um erro
>   desconhecido ao processar a solicitação no servidor. O código de
>   status retornado do servidor foi: 500

Me pareçe que o Asp.net está barrando o HTML do componente.
Já estou usando o **ValidateRequest="false"**.

Meu código

```
<%@ Page UICulture="auto" ValidateRequest="false"  Culture="auto" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ius/MasterPage.master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CadastroNormas.aspx.cs" Inherits="CadastroNormas"
    Title="Cadastro de Normas" AsyncTimeout="600" %>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlArquivos" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
        <ContentTemplate>
           <span class="txtCampo">Texto da Norma:</span><br />
             <asp:TextBox ID="Spaw2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="100"
                  Columns="100"></asp:TextBox>
                 <br />
                 <br />
              </ContentTemplate>                           
             </asp:UpdatePanel>

           tinyMCE.init(
           {
               mode: "specific_textareas",
               editor_selector: "mceEditor",
               height: "400",
               theme: "modern",
               entity_encoding: "raw",

               content_css: "../estilo.css",

               //Hacks para manter a formatação vinda do word
               forced_root_block: false,
               paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: false,
               paste_text_use_dialog: true,
               paste_force_cleanup_paste: false,
               paste_remove_spans: false,
               paste_retain_style_properties: "margin, padding, width, height, font-size, font-weight, font-family, color, text-align, ul, ol, li, text-decoration, border, background, float, display"

           });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema, como você deve ter determinado, é a formatação HTML do conteúdo do tinyMCE: o ASP.Net entende este conteúdo como inseguro e bloqueia a requisição.

Pode ser que você tenha colocado o `ValidateRequest="false"` no lugar errado. O correto é colocá-lo na diretriz `Page`:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ValidateRequest="false"%>
```

E no seu web.conf você deve colocar

```
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

A melhor solução, na minha opinião, é escrever um handler para o evento `onclick` do botão `submit` e converter o texto para HTML Encoded em um `StringBuilder`.

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<html>  
  <body>  
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
      <div>  
        <asp:textbox id="htmlInputTxt" runat="server" textmode="MultiLine" width="318px" height="168px">  
        </asp:textbox>  
        <asp:button id="submitBtn" runat="server" text="Submit" onclick="submitBtn_Click">  
        </asp:button>  
      </div>  
    </form>  
  </body>  
</html>
```

O processamento do `onclick` na página `.aspx` que processa a requisição é:

```
<script runat="server">  
  void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(htmlInputTxt.Text));  
    Response.Write(sb.ToString());  
  }  
</script>
```

Os códigos e a dica é uma versão que venho utilizando em meus projetos e foram originalmente obtidos neste [link](http://devtacular.com/articles/gkonrad/allowing-html-formatted-user-input-in-aspnet/).

Adicionar `requestValidationMode="2.0"` especifica que deve ser utilizado o estilo de validação do .Net 2, ao invés do 4, que é o padrão no caso de você estar utilizando o .Net 4.

No .Net 2, a validação só ocorre para requisições de páginas, e não para todas as demais como as de Ajax, e, além disso, as configurações de validação de página no arquivo de configurações ou na diretriz `Page` da sua página são levadas em consideração.

O .Net 4, ao contrário, ignora estas configurações. Por isso da minha preferência por não utilizar estas configurações de validação e sim utilizar o método com `StringBuilder`. Porém, não me ocorreu que você estava utilizando o .Net 4 na minha respota inicial.

Comment: Estou colocando o ValidateRequest="false" na diretiva Page mesmo. Meu problema que o vento de click não  chama meu aspx.cs

Comment: Complete sua questão com mais código. Do jeito que está, só isso é possível inferir.

Comment: <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
Coloquei isso no meu código e funcionou. Poderia me explicar o porque? Grato.

Comment: Complementei minha resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: você acha melhor trocar a pergunta para ela ficar mais generica? Colocar tipo. Validação de idas ao servidor com componentes de texto HTML.

Comment: Acho que tanto faz, porque tanto a busca do Google quanto a busca do SO já considera o texto da pergunta.